# Java int comparing, cannot figure out what is wrong

Tags: java, int

I am novice at Java, but I can't seem to understand why this code always prints 66! The code

```
for (int x = 0; x < columns; ++x) {

        for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {

            Cell cell = getCell(x, y);

            int gridX = (int)cell.getXFromGridX();
            int gridY = (int)cell.getYFromGridY();

            if (((int)cell.getX()) == gridX && ((int)cell.getGridY()) == gridY) {

                continue;
            }

            ++count;
            log("CELL ANIMATING", (int)cell.getX() + "   " + gridX + "   :::   " + (int)cell.getY() + "   " + gridY);
```

Basically the for loops iterate over 66 items and if their gridX == X and their gridY == Y then the count should not go up and nothing should be output to the console.

However I get output of, (just a selection)

CELL ANIMATING﹕ 300   300   :::   480   400

CELL ANIMATING﹕ 300   300   :::   1000   480

CELL ANIMATING﹕ 360   360   :::   80   80

CELL ANIMATING﹕ 360   360   :::   160   160

CELL ANIMATING﹕ 360   360   :::   240   240

The output clearly shows that the gridX == X and gridY == Y in some cases.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The cell methods used above all return floats.

Comment: Post the cell class, I can't tell anything from what you posted

Comment: All the cell methods above return floats.

Comment: xD Forgot it was part of the JRE runtime

Comment: *I can't seem to understand why this code always prints 66!* I cannot find any part of your code where you get 66.

Comment: use break; instead of continue;

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ye sorry for that I count and print the result after the loop! My apologies.

Comment: @OakNinja but then I wouldn't test all cells

Comment: Why the downvote, I was a valid problem which I could not solve for some time and I did try and research. Some people!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `if` condition you're checking:

```
cell.getGridY()
```

while in the log printing you're checking:

```
(int)cell.getY()
```

and these calls probably return different values.

Comment: This had me stumped for a long time, how dumb of me!!! Thanks for your keen eye!!

Answer (score 1):

Change cell.getGridY() to cell.getY() in your if statement

```
        if (((int)cell.getX()) == gridX && ((int)cell.getGridY()) == gridY) {
```